# Casting unsigned char to signed char for a red-black tree

Tags: c++, qt, casting

### Overview

I'm working on wrapping Windows Shell functionality with Qt. The issue I've run into regards `ABSOLUTE_IDLIST`s and storing the data. For reference, a 
Windows id list looks like this in memory:

```
//Note that there may be an arbitrary number of cb/abId pairs.
=================================================================
=           =   (cb bytes)  =           =  (cb bytes)   =       =
= USHORT cb =  UCHAR []abID = USHORT cb =  UCHAR []abId = '\0'  =
=================================================================
```

I'm using the absolute ID as a unique identifier for each node for quick
retrieval. The value type is `ShellNodePointer`, a shared pointer to `ShellNode`, which caches data. I originally approached this using 
`QHash` (basically `std::unordored_map`), but that requires hashing the bits for every retrieval (although I stored the hash key in the ShellNode).

```
//unsigned int is the hash result, ShellNodePointer is a QSharedPointer to a ShellNode
QHash<unsigned int, ShellNodePointer>
```

Instead, I'm considering a red-black tree approach using `QMap`. My issue is
this: the fastest way to compare two keys would be storing them as `QByteArray`s, which would allow quick less than comparisons and simple passing of the id list as raw data to the `QByteArray` constructor.

```
ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE *someIdListPointer = ...;
QByteArray ba(someIdListPointer);
```

### The Problem

Unfortunately, QByteArray takes a null-terminated `const char *`, without
specificying signed or unsigned. Since I'm on Windows, this defaults to signed
char.

### The Question

Can I cast to `[signed] char *` and disregard the overflow issues, since every negative value key will overflow in the same way? Specifically, will the red-black tree still work as normal, since the resulting data is guaranteed to be uniform in two separate calls with the same key?

Note: I am aware the the `USHORT cb` will be included in the key. This is acceptable, as it's just extra data that will be matched with two identical keys.

Edit: clarified that `abId` is actually an array without a null-terminator.

Comment: Which overflow issues? Casting the pointer to a different type means you're interpreting the bytes differently (just like other signed/unsigned casts) and cannot possibly overflow. Also, while two's complement representation for signed integral types is not guaranteed by the standard, it is a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I want to make sure that I won't run into problems comparing keys.

Comment: Assuming that you don't care about the actual order inside the RB tree, you can treat/look at the data bytes any which way you want for the comparison, even something like `int32_t`s (assuming the list is properly aligned). The two's complement thing is also irrelevant then. I am more confused by the discrepancy between `QByteArray` taking a null-terminated char sequence when only the entire list is null-terminated, not the individual keys. But maybe this is a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Regarding null termination: `cbID` is not null terminated, only the entire structure.

Comment: What is `cbID`?

Comment: Oops. `abID`, the substrings in the structure. `abId` is the byte count for the substring, `cbId` a raw character array. The entire thing is then singly null-terminated. See the memory diagram above. I've edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: The diagram suggests the opposite of what you just said (`cb` being the byte count and `abId` being the character array). It does not mention `cbId`. Regardless, the structure is quite clear and it appears to me that the `QByteArray` for the first list node will include the entire remaining list as its value, not just the first `cb` and `abId`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Correct. I made a typo in referring to `cbId`, meaning `abId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I cast to [signed] char * and disregard the overflow issues, since every negative value key will overflow in the same way? Specifically, will the red-black tree still work as normal, since the resulting data is guaranteed to be uniform in two separate calls with the same key?

Yes, casting like this simply interprets the bytes in memory in a different way and will be consistent for identical machine + executable/compiler. The byte representation of signed integers is not mandated by the standard, so the "meaning" (i.e. represented number) may not be what you expect, but that should not matter for a RB tree that just requires a total ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience, Max.